# loading label is misplaced on extjs combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have an ext.data.store and Ext.form.field.ComboBox. The store is reloaded with new data from php every 5 seconds. The problem I get is, when i press the combo box and new data is loaded at the moment the loading label that shows the preloader is places or in top left corner or behind the combo box or somewhere in the middle of the screen if i move the combo window.

How can I fix this or what do I do wrong?

Here is a sample code:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'id',  type: 'string'},
    {name: 'type',   type: 'int'},
    {name: 'myarray', type: 'auto'}
],
```

});

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'MyModel',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : '/users.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'MyModel'
    }
},
autoLoad: true
});

var createCombo = function(){
// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: myStore ,
    queryMode: 'remote',
    displayField: 'type',
    valueField: 'id'
});

}

createCombo ();
```

I made this code as my code I am using in development. It works well but the loading label is misplaced

Comment: Can you post the code? a jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: I dont have the code at the moment, but any generic code for store and combo is acceptable. The store uses model and the store is reloaded with new data every 5 secs. The store is associated to the combobox.

Comment: ok let me do some sample code